# Applying conditions in ng-show and ng-hide

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular JS, I got stuck up with this code, While I am reading the tutorials, I got stuck up with this code on Angular JS. Please help me on that.

More particularly how 'AfterClicked' is working in controlling the visibility of the DIV elements.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myModel">
<head>
    <title>Begin with Angular</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- Adding the Bootstrap style sheet-->
    <link href="Styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <!-- Adding the Angular File-->
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/MainM.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="myController as control">

        <div ng-hide="AfterClicked">
            {{control.title}}

            <a href="#" ng-click="AfterClicked=!AfterClicked">click To Edit</a>
        </div>

        <div ng-show="AfterClicked">
            <input ng-model="control.title">

            <a href="#" ng-click="AfterClicked=!AfterClicked">Done Editing??</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS Code:

```
/// <reference path="angular.js" />
var myApp = angular.module("myModel", [])
                .controller("myController", function () {
                    this.title = "Welcome to Angular",
                    this.AfterClick=0
                });
```

It's working fine, The thing that i got stuck up is "AfterClicked", How it's working in ng-show, ng-hide and ng-click in anchor tags.

Please help me on that..!!

Comment: What is the expected behavior, can you please explain

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer:**

When you don't define an object in AngularJS controller code but use it in the template, Angular creates that object and it's assigned empty string value. So, in this case, even though you did not assign any value to `AfterClicked` in JS code, it was created by Angular and set to ``. This evaluates to false and the div is hidden.
You can check the value in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/12053/

---

Firstly, couple of mistakes in the code.

1.There is a typo with `AfterClicked` in JS code.

2.Since you are using the `myController as control` syntax, ng-click on the anchor tag should use `control.AfterClicked` and not `AfterClicked`.

Now in JS code, `AfterClicked` is being set to `0`, which evaluates to false in JS.

In the `ng-hide="AfterClicked"` code, `AfterClicked` evaluates to false and hence angular hides the div.

In the anchor tag code `ng-click="AfterClicked=!AfterClicked"`,means that on click of anchor tag, the expression `"AfterClicked=!AfterClicked"` is evaluated ,which negates `AfterClicked`.

Comment: yeah as you mentioned in my JS code I have defined AfterClick unnecessarily without defining that in my JS code how AfterClicked in my HTML is working.?? Whether by default it is taking as value "0". For better understanding please refer the below link http://jsfiddle.net/timriley/5DMjt/

Comment: Updated the answer. Angular automatically creates the variable from the template, you don't have to declare or assign in JS code.